# Where to Default Value in a Self Asserted Technical Profile

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

If I want to default a value in my self-asserted `TechnicalProfile`, do I default it in my `InputClaims` or `OutputClaims`?

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="MySelfAssertTp">
    <DisplayName>Blah</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        ...
    </Metadata>
        ...
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domain_hint" DefaultValue="HERE 1" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domain_hint" DefaultValue="HERE 2" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I default it in my `InputClaims` or `OutputClaims`?

You have to add your default value in the **output claim**.